# How to add line to TOP of text file?

Tags: vbscript, text-files, qtp, hp-uft

I need to insert a line at the top of a text file. If I use `WriteLine()` method, it will just append the line to the end of the file.

Btw, I'm using VBScript in QTP (UFT).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Append the content of the text file to your top line, overwrite the text file with the string:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = "31144630.txt"
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sAll : sAll     = "top line " & Now & vbCrLf
If goFS.FileExists(csFSpec) Then sAll = sAll & goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec).ReadAll()
goFS.CreateTextFile(csFSpec).Write sAll
```

output:

```
cscript 31144630.vbs

type 31144630.txt
top line 6/30/2015 7:57:07 PM

cscript 31144630.vbs

type 31144630.txt
top line 6/30/2015 7:57:25 PM
top line 6/30/2015 7:57:07 PM
```